# Serving Multiple Domains in Django

Tags: python, django

I currently have 2 domains that I want to share a single Django project via the use of Apache (and wsgi)
I've used the following guide that I have found here: http://www.fir3net.com/Django/how-to-serve-multiple-domains-from-within-a-single-django-project.html

To note: Domain 1 isn't using a database but domain2 is. And I currently have a single database configured within the main settings.py file.

The issue I first had is that the template for domain1 was found but for domain2 it was unable to locate it. After some troubleshooting I added the TEMPLATE_DIRs to the domain2_settings.py file. Even though I would of expected this to be picked up by the main settings.py file.
Now I am getting an error that domain2 is unable to find a database and from the debug output it shows that there is no database assigned. Even though I would of expected the database settings to be be pulled from the main settings.py file.

Heres a summary of my layout:

```
/opt/
`-- django
    |
    `-- myproject
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- domain1
        |   |-- __init__.py
        |   |-- domain1.wsgi
        |   |-- domain1_settings.py
        |   |-- domain1_urls.py
        |   |-- models.py
        |   |-- tests.py
        |   |-- views.py
        |-- domain2
        |   |-- __init__.py
        |   |-- domain2.wsgi
        |   |-- domain2_settings.py
        |   |-- domain2_urls.py
        |   |-- models.py
        |   |-- tests.py
        |   |-- views.py
        |-- manage.py
        |-- settings.py
        |-- templates
        |   |-- domain1-base.html
        |   |-- domain2-base.html
        `-- urls.py
```

**settings.py**

```
[root@william myproject]# cat settings.py
# Django settings for myproject project.

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '123',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '123',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '##########',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': ''                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    },
}
```

**domain2_settings.py**

```
[root@william myproject]#  cat domain2/domain2_settings.py
from settings import *

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

SITE_ID = 2

ROOT_URLCONF = 'domain2.domain2_urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        "/opt/django/myproject/templates"
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'domain2',
)
```

Am I going about this the correct way (i.e multiple domains, single project, apache and using a single database)?

Comment: Looks like you've created one 'project' with two 'apps'. If the two sites are different, they should be two separate 'projects'. If they're very similar, you can do it in one 'project' with one 'app'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I still had a settings.py and urls.py file within the domain2 folder. Once I removed these the issue was resolved.